# how to divide text after symbol into rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apply, melt

im trying to divide text from each symbol from one long text.

| Column 1 |
| --- |
| C9 ban Pearl; LEV ban Fracture; C9 pick Lotus; LEV pick Haven; C9 ban Split; LEV ban Ascent; Bind remains |

and i need to tranform this long text into this table

| Team | pb_phase | Map |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C9 | ban | Pearl |
| LEV | ban | Fracture |
| C9 | pick | Lotus |
| LEV | pick | Haven |
| C9 | ban | Split |
| LEV | ban | Ascent |

im expecting to divide each symbol to each row and then divide text from each row into 3 different column (team,pb_phase, and map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), agins `split` and set new columns names by [`DataFrame.set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html):

```
out = (df['Column 1'].str.split(';\s*')
                    .explode()
                    .str.split(expand=True)
                    .set_axis(['Team','pb_phase','Map'], axis=1)
                    .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Or add `expand=True` for first `split` and use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
out = (df['Column 1'].str.split(';\s*', expand=True)
                     .stack()
                    .str.split(expand=True)
                    .set_axis(['Team','pb_phase','Map'], axis=1)
                    .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Or use list comprehension for lists and pass to Dataframe constructor:

```
out = pd.DataFrame([y.split() for x in df['Column 1'] for y in x.split('; ')],
                   columns=['Team','pb_phase','Map'])
```

---

```
print (out)
   Team pb_phase       Map
0    C9      ban     Pearl
1   LEV      ban  Fracture
2    C9     pick     Lotus
3   LEV     pick     Haven
4    C9      ban     Split
5   LEV      ban    Ascent
6  Bind  remains      None
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```
(pd.DataFrame(
    df['Column 1'].str.split(';').explode().map(lambda x: x.split()).to_list(), 
    columns=['Team','pb_phase', 'Map']))
```

Output:

```
   Team pb_phase       Map
0    C9      ban     Pearl
1   LEV      ban  Fracture
2    C9     pick     Lotus
3   LEV     pick     Haven
4    C9      ban     Split
5   LEV      ban    Ascent
6  Bind  remains      None
```